# Unable to send SMPT mails using phpMailer from a newly created email via gmail

Tags: yii, smtp, phpmailer

My email is working when i use my own email address but I need to run this using website's newly create email. This email is created using gmail.

Here's my code:

```
function phpMailer($emailTo, $subject, $body)
    {

        $email_temp = $body;
        $to = $emailTo;
        Yii::import('application.extensions.phpmailer.JPhpMailer');
        $mail = new JPhpMailer;
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        //$mail->Host = 'smtp.googlemail.com:465';
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->Port = 587;//465;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPDebug = true;
        $mail->Username = 'info@domainname.com';
        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxx';
        $mail->SetFrom('info@domainname.com', 'domainname'); //Send 'From' User
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->AltBody = $email_temp;
        $mail->MsgHTML($email_temp); // message /template 
        $mail->AddAddress($to); //Send mail 'To' User 

        //check if mail sent successfully
        if($mail->Send())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

I am getting following response when debug using code 2.

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c3sm6277150qge.12 - gsmtp " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c3sm6277150qge.12 - gsmtp " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c3sm6277150qge.12 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.209.41.153] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 w1qusykfYpU2yVqlT4ZEIFrXPep3JwRh3FfzQc7ddey5QQmBd4JbZi9tNFSnBFHW7IdOcx " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 NbZA5LEBoeSZEcjcwhBW_Kfziy5pHrZal2opZ3uBdoF-WM4OPoMDnfG_w_7fNOtjA8HGPw " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 zL0OcSfQMG3sJ1fwVuYZTRL3prN6EZudpmCgygKIv1lqW9r7w8fXC5v-3qGXWP3PxghHp8 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 fVgbNTqeHZhv728Su3O-QGwFNdsU> Please log in via your web browser and " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 then try again. " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 Learn more at " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 c3sm6277150qge.12 - gsmtp " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 c3sm6277150qge.12 - gsmtp " 
SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 c3sm6277150qge.12 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 2.1.5 Flushed c3sm6277150qge.12 - gsmtp " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 2.1.5 Flushed c3sm6277150qge.12 - gsmtp " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 Flushed c3sm6277150qge.12 - gsmtp 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Comment: Please, just read your error message that tells you to go [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754). You're running an old version of [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and you've based your code on a long-obsolete example. There are hundreds of duplicates of this question, and it's covered extensively in [the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). Really, you're just not trying.

Comment: @Synchro: Not really I was using my own gmail email until now and the mails was working fine. Today I implemented client's email which he bought for his website and mails stopped working. When I debug, i get the above messages. The problem wasn't in code at all. This happened due to google's more secured settings for emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. You need to enforce access to less secure apps from link. [less secure apps setting](http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) or if you have configured email from google mail apps then go to admin->security->basic setting and do the above.